# How to rename a CSV file from a value in the CSV file

Tags: bash

I have 100 1-line CSV files. The files are currently labeled AAA.txt, AAB.txt, ABB.txt (after I used `split -l 1` on them). The first field in each of these files is what I want to rename the file as, so instead of AAA, AAB and ABB it would be the first value.

Input CSV (filename AAA.txt)

```
1234ABC, stuff, stuff
```

Desired Output (filename 1234ABC.csv)

```
1234ABC, stuff, stuff
```

I don't want to edit the content of the CSV itself, just change the filename

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear, please do  add more details in your post and do let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
for f in ./* ; do new_name=$(head -1 $f | cut -d, -f1); cp $f dir/$new_name
```

move them into a new dir just in case something goes wrong, or you need the original file names.

Answer (score 1):

starting with your original file before splitting

```
$ awk -F, '{print > ($1".csv")}' originalFile.csv
```

and do all in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

This will store the whole input file into the `colum1.csv` of the inputfile.

```
awk -F, '{print $0 > $1".csv" }' aaa.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, changed directory, e.g. `cd /path/to/directory` that the files are in and then use the following *compound command*:

```
for f in *.txt; do echo mv -n "$f" "$(awk -F, '{print $1}' "$f").cvs"; done
```

Note: There is an intensional `echo` *command* that is there for you to test with, and it will only print out the `mv` *command* for you to see that it's the outcome you wish. You can then run it again removing just `echo` from the *compound command* to actually rename the files as desired via the `mv` *command*.